# Suppose $v^T(A^{-1} - B^{-1})v\geq 0$ for any vector $v$, show that $u^T(B - A)u \geq 0$ for any vector $u$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $p\times p$ invertible, symmetric matrices with positive eigenvalues (i.e., positive definite) and that

$$v^T(A^{-1} - B^{-1})v\geq 0$$
for any vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^p$.

How can I show that

$$u^T(B - A)u \geq 0$$
for any vector $u \in \mathbb{R}^p$?

Since $u^TBu$ and $u^TAu$ are scalars, I was hoping to take the inverse, i.e., $\frac{1}{u^TBu}$ and $\frac{1}{u^TAu}$ and relate them to $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ somehow. But I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Unless we are given that $A,B$ are symmetric with positive eigenvalues, I believe that this is generally false

Comment: I added this information to the original post

Comment: Related [see](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wner-Heinz_inequality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and positive definite, then, we can decompose them as follows

$ A = A_1^T A_1 $ and $B = B_1^T B_1$ for real invertible matrices $A_1$ and $B_1$

Now we're gvien that

$ v^T (A^{-1} - B^{-1} ) v \ge 0 $

Using the Cholesky factorization above, we can write

$ v^T ( A_1^{-1} A_1^{-T} - B_1^{-1} B_1^{-T} ) v \ge 0 $

And this equals

$ v^T A_1^{-1} ( I - A_1 B_1^{-1} B_1^{-T} A_1^T ) A_1^{-T} v \ge 0 $

we can now replace $ A_1^{-T} v $ with the vector $w$, and replace the matrix $B_1^{-T} A_1^T$ with $C$, so we'll have

$ w^T (I - C^T C ) w \ge 0 $

What this means is that $\lambda_{\text{Max}}( C^T C ) \le 1 $

Hence,  $ \lambda_{\text{Min}} (C^{-1} C^{-T} ) \ge 1 $

But $C^{-1} C^{-T} = A_1^{-T} B_1^T B_1 A_1^{-1} = A_1^{-T} B A_1^{-1} $

Hence, we now know that for any vector $z$

$ z^T ( C^{-1} C^{-T} - I ) z \ge 0 $

Substitute $C^{-1}C^{-T} $

$ z^T ( A_1^{-T} B A_1^{-1} - I ) z \ge 0 $

Pull out the $A_1^{-T} $ and $A_1^{-1}$ , then

$ z^T A_1^{-T} ( B - A_1^T A_1 ) A_1^{-1} z  \ge 0 $

And this is, finally,

$ z^T A_1^{-T} ( B - A) A_1^{-1} z \ge 0 $

Since $z$ is arbitrary and $A_1$ is invertible then $A_1^{-1} z$ is arbitrary (any vector).  Thus we have proven that

$ u^T (B - A) u \ge 0 \hspace{10pt} \forall u $

Answer (score 0):

Let $M := A^{-1} - B^{-1}$. We have $A = (B^{-1} + M)^{-1}$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 B - A &= B - (B^{-1} + M)^{-1}\\
 &= (B^{-1} + M)^{-1}[(B^{-1} + M)B(B^{-1} + M) - (B^{-1} + M)](B^{-1} + M)^{-1}\\
 &= (B^{-1} + M)^{-1}[M + MBM](B^{-1} + M)^{-1}.
\end{align*}

Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
 u^\mathsf{T}(B - A)u
 = u_1^\mathsf{T}M u_1 +  (Mu_1)^\mathsf{T} B (M u_1) \ge 0
\end{align*}
where $u_1 = (B^{-1} + M)^{-1}u$.

We are done.